# In PhpStorm, how can I remove file masks?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I've added some custom file masks, and sometimes misspelled a file masks and PhpStorm remembers all of these, which is annoying.

How can I clear the list of file masks in the search free text modal?

Comment: Please provide screenshots -- it's not clear (for me at very least) what "file masks" you are talking about.

Comment: @LazyOne I suppose the OP is referring to the content of the "File mask(s)" dropdown in the "Find in Path" dialog box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to edit the `config/options/find.xml` file in your [PhpStorm IDE settings directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/project-and-ide-settings.html).

Comment: The pleasant part of it is that the file is reloaded every time the "Find in Path" dialog  box opens. Any change you do to it applies immediately, there is no need to restart PhpStorm :-)

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

I use WebStorm v2020.3 on OS X (10.14/Mojave). I don't know if it will be of any use to anyone but the answer above helped me figure out where this file could be found. I found that editing `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.2/options/find.xml` and then restarting WebStorm was what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 the file is located at %APPDATA%\JetBrains<product>\options